# Node.js api - Can we get accuracy distance between two latlong as per google map giving result in distance?

Tags: node.js

In our mobile application has location based features. So i had implemented npm geodist for getting distance (used by haversine formula) between two coordinates. The geodist distance result is different with google map result. Can i get the distance result in npm geodist as per same google map has provided. Please anybody help regarding this. Thanks in advance

```
var geodist = require('geodist')
var distance = geodist({lat: 11.0145, lon: 76.9864}, {lat: 11.0167, lon: 76.9774}, {exact: true, unit: 'km'})
```

I am getting result in 1.01 km in accuracy mode.

But the same i had tested in google map between two places from - 'Ukkadam Bus Shed, Ukkadam, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641008' and to 'Noble Business Centre, Avinashi Rd, P N Palayam, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641037' - its giving result 5.8 km

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I did it. First, getting results that requiring distance values.

```
public static getDetails = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
       // Our application's user current position received from browser
        const latitude = req.query.lat;
        const longitude = req.query.long;
        await new sql.ConnectionPool(CommonConstants.connectionString).connect().then(pool => {
            return pool.request()
                .input('Id', sql.Int, id)
                .execute('GetSupplierDetails')
        }).then(result => {
            sql.close();
            const rows = result.recordset.map(async (supplier) => {
                const data = { origin: [latitude, longitude], destination: [supplier.Latitude, supplier.Longitude] }; // Setting coordinates here
                const distance = await GetDistance(data) || 0;
                Object.defineProperty(supplier, 'Distance', {
                    enumerable: true,
                    configurable: true,
                    writable: true,
                    value: distance
                });
                return supplier;
            });
            Promise.all(rows).then((values) => {
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                res.status(200).json(values);
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err })
            sql.close();
        });
        sql.on('error', err => {
            // ... error handler
        });
    }
```

And that is the function that connects to Google Distance Matrix API.

```
import { Constants } from "./constants";
const https = require('https');

export async function GetDistance(coords) {
    const { origin, destination } = coords;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(`${Constants.GoogleMapsUrl}?origins=${origin[0]},${origin[1]}
         &destinations=${destination[0]},${destination[1]}
         &key=${Constants.GoogleMapsApiKey}`, (resp) => {
            let data = '';
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });
            resp.on('end', () => {
                const distance = JSON.parse(data);
                resolve(distance.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value);
            });
        }).on("error", (err) => {
            reject("Error: " + err.message);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @andrey.shedko for the prompt response. I will implement and get back soon

Comment: Thanks indeed @andrey.shedko. I got result thorugh this. But Distance matrix API is payable. Is it possible way in another way?

Comment: @Tkavi, you may try the other providers.